# how do i post a variable?

Tags: html, var

I'll re-explain my situation because i think my initial story wasn't clear enough.
Im programming a webpage in Visual Studio, it's in C#, but my actual question is about the HTML portion.

I already succesfully implemented localization. Only problem is i can only change language by hardcoding it (for example i can hardcode language="EN", and my site will be in english)

now , of course i dont want to hardcode it, i want people to choose there language. So i need a button that can make the same page reload in another language.

I only need one thing after the reload, and that is the string "en" or "nl" (depending on chosen language). So my button sends me to index.aspx, but my fresh page doesn't know the value of the button i just pressed.

how do I pass variables?

Comment: thx for the edit, what was wrong with my original post? i tried many times

Comment: Maybe you should give us some context.

Comment: Do you have two separate HTML pages for those two languages? Or are the pages dynamic and you're loading the content from a database?

Comment: What is the programming language you want to use? Or do you need a solution that only handles static html pages?

Comment: look into using a html query string. all you will have to do is <a href="http://www.your-domain.com?lang=NL">Dutch</a> and in your html page fire some javascript that retrieves query strings and then do something with it.

Comment: sorry for the little detail i removed many cause the site wouldnt accept my typing, ill try to add more detail

Comment: Have you tried completing some HTML tutorials before asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay,

They way i would go about this question is to use a  to list all the languages that you want to include:

```
<form method="get" action="Index.aspx">
<label for="language">Select you language here</label>
<select id="language">
<option value="english"English</option>
<option value="french">French</option>
. 
.
.
</select>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

and then do some processing in your aspx file

--EDIT--

if you use method="get" in the form the variable chosen will be appended to the url in such a way:

```
index.aspx?language=english /* for example */
```

in your aspx page you can run some javascript:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
//  Parse Query String
    var queryString = new Object;
    var qstr=window.location.search.substring(1);
    var params=qstr.split('&');
    for (var i=0; i<params.length; i++) {
      var pair=params[i].split('=');
      queryString[pair[0]]=pair[1];
    }
   //]]> 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   var language = queryString['language'];
   if (language== "english") {
        /* Do some processing */
    }
    else { do domething else }
</script>
```

If you place the javascript in the head it will run when the page loads. In the processing part access your language files.

Comment: or alternatively use method="get" and then the variable in the form will be on the end of your url ?language=

Comment: thanks for your reaction. My biggest problem is retrieving the language i just set, you say 'do some processing', but i wouldnt know how.
btw the file that this code is in, actually is Index.aspx

Comment: thanks again for all your help. im getting the feeling im almost there :P however the variable does not get appended to my link, in firefox i see nothing in my url, in chrome i just see http://localhost:57688/? - so guess the variable isnt set (it was just localhost i had to link 2, not index.aspx). still think its strange that implementing localization is easier then passing a variable to the next page lol :P

Comment: i agree. try using the entire url in the action of the form. the HTTP GET method definitely works in this way so i am unsure why that is not working. Let me know if you need any more help! You could always use the JS above when hard coding the append to the url use <a href="index.aspx?language=NL">Make this page Dutch</a> This is a great way to test the JS code is working.

Comment: i just continued working on it, but i got it to work thanks man!! no thanks to the idiots who closed this post

Answer (score 1):

You could do this a couple different ways. One you could just put the entire language site in a sub directory, so it would be like:

www.example.com/english/index.php

Or another way would be to use get like you said, and for each page just store the english and the dutch, and only display the language in the url (default could be dutch). So calling your page like this: (assuming your using php)

for english:

www.example.com/index.php?lan=english

for dutch: (no language is defined, dutch is default language)

www.example.com/index.php

In your page (you'd want to do this for each page that is able to be read in english and dutch:

```
<?php
$lan = 'dutch';
if(isset($_GET['lan']))
     $lan = $_GET['lan'];

if($lan == 'english')
{
     ... Your page in english ...
}
else
{
     ... Default Language ...
}
?>
```

Comment: no, i have 1 page for all languages, i already succesfully implemented Localization, so i just want to reload the same page but with a different value of language. I'm using visual studio mvc4 template
but i guess i can put the php between <script> tags? ill try

Comment: after this code, i would have to use $lan in my aspx code around this block, but the aspx part doesnt recognize $lan as variable...